# Facing Problem in installing Vlc

Tags: apt

Thank you for the previous answer. There is one more thing I want to know.

I am not able to install vlc (see picture below).

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of terminal output (it is very hard to read). Copy the text directly and format it as `code` instead. Also, if the answer to your previous question helped you solving your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message suggests, that another process is using the dpkg lock.

From your screenshot, I can see that you have a second Terminal open with root login. You should check, if there is an `apt` process running there, wait until it is finished and then try again.